# How can i have my Agent only take a Step when he is automatically requested to by my custom gym-environment?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, simpy, stable-baselines

i am trying to implement an reinforcement agent, which decides on choosing machines for orders on a production site. I created a custom env in Simpy which asks the Agent on different times, what machines he wants to choose for specific orders, unfortunately i cannot figure out how to implement, that the environment has the leading role: the agent should only do something when he is asked for his action.

My Environment works like this: In the reset- function the Simpy simulation gets started, for every first operation for every order in an orderbook, the agent is asked to select the machine (def initProcesses(), def step()). After each order is finished(def OnTimeoutComplete()) the next operation should be scheduled by the agent(again def Step() is activated). Also new orders are created simultaneously, which should immediately get scheduled.

For implementation at the end i create a gym-env instance of the class and activate the reset function, which is supposed to trigger the Simpy- simulation.

I get the Error: "TypeError: Step() missing 1 required positional argument: 'action'", which i suppose is from my incorrect implementation of the step- function.

Is it possible to implement my env, the way i described or do i have to remodel it, by involving everything in the step- func and let it get activated by the agent? I would very much appreciate your help as this is my first project involving RL and i am keen to get more understanding. Thank you!

```
#Import Libraries
    #common Libraries
import random
import simpy
import numpy
import queue

    #gym Libraries
import gym
from gym import spaces
from gym.spaces import Discrete, Box, Dict

    #sb3 Libraries
from stable_baselines3 import PPO
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import VecFrameStack
from stable_baselines3.common.evaluation import evaluate_policy
from stable_baselines3.common.env_checker import check_env

class FJSP(gym.Env):


#Initialize action- and statespace
        def __init__(self,nMachinesPerOperation):
            super(FJSP, self).__init__()
            self.action_space = spaces.Discrete(low = 0, high = max(nMachinesPerOperation), shape = (1,))
            self.observation_space = spaces.Dict(
                spaces = {
                        "AuftragVariante": spaces.Discrete(4),
                        ##"AuftragOperationstyp": spaces.Discrete(3),
                        ##"AuftragOperationszeit": spaces.Box(0,1,shape=(1,),dtype=numpy.float32),
                        ##"AuftragSlackzeit": spaces.Box(0,1,shape=(1,),dtype=numpy.float32),
                        ##"AuftragFortschritt": spaces.Box(0,1,shape=(1,),dtype=numpy.float32),
                        ##"AuftragErwartungVerspätung": spaces.Discrete(1),
                        ##"SystemVerweildauer": spaces.Box(0,1,shape=(1,),dtype=numpy.float32),
                        ##"StandardabweichungPufferauslastung": spaces.Box(0,1,shape=(1,),dtype=numpy.float32),
                        ##"MaschineMedianPufferauslastung": spaces.Box(0,1,shape=(1,),dtype=numpy.float32),
                        ##"SystemMedianPufferauslastung": spaces.Box(0,1,shape=(1,),dtype=numpy.float32)
            })
            self.state = 0
            
    
#CreateOrders Functions


    #Initializes by starting a process
        def CreateOrdersInit(self,env):
            self.env.process(self.yieldCreateOrdersEvents(env))
            yield self.env.timeout(1)   #needed for beeing a Generator function

    #Yield Timeouts and set callback function for when timeout is done
        def yieldCreateOrdersEvents(self,env):
            self.TimeoutCreateOrders=self.env.timeout(random.randint(self.TimespanCreateorders*0.8,self.TimespanCreateorders*1.2))
            self.TimeoutCreateOrders.callbacks.append(lambda event: self.AtCreateOrdersEvents(env))
            yield self.env.timeout(1)   #needed for beeing a Generator function

    #After timeout finished order with random variant will be created
        def AtCreateOrdersEvents(self,env):
            self.VariantChoice = random.randint(0, len(self.Variants)-1)
            for a in range(self.nOrders):
                if self.Orderbook[a][0][2] ==  self.nOperationsPerVariant[self.Orderbook[a][0][1]]:
                        self.Orderbook[a][0][0] = env.now+258*self.nOrders*self.StrictnessDeadline
                        self.Orderbook[a][0][1] = self.VariantChoice  
                        self.Orderbook[a][0][2] = 0 #Counter for Operations in this order
                        for b in range(1, self.nOperationsPerVariant[self.VariantChoice]+1):
                            self.Orderbook[a][b][0] = self.Variants[self.VariantChoice][b-1][0]
                            self.Orderbook[a][b][1] = self.Variants[self.VariantChoice][b-1][1]
                            self.Orderbook[a][b][2] = 1 
                        print("Creating new Order:",self.Orderbook[a],"in Line:",a,"at Time",self.env.now)
                        print("Starting new order: Order,Operation:",a,0)
                        self.env.process(self.step(env,a,1))            
                        break
                else:
                    print("no slots free at time ", self.env.now)
            self.env.process(self.yieldCreateOrdersEvents(env))
        

#Main Functions


    #Initialize Processes for each order at time 0
        def initProcesses(self,env):
            for i in range(self.nOrders):
                self.env.process(self.step(env,i,1))
            yield self.env.timeout(1) #needed for beeing a Generator function

#Step- function
    #Choosing Resource       
        def step(self,env,i,j,action):                       
                if env.now > 7000:#self.episodeLength:
                    self.done = True
                    self.reset()
                

                #Action will be inserted instead of next line
                [j][0])]) #chooses random Resource out of the needed Resourcegroup
                
                #simple action masking
                if self.Orderbook[i][j][0] == 0 or self.Orderbook[i][j][0] == 2:
                    if action == 4:
                          action = 0 
                    if action == 5:
                          action = 1
                    if self.Orderbook[i][j][0] == 2:
                        if action == 2:
                          action = 0 
                        elif action == 3:
                          action = 1
                
                #Putting order in queues
                self.OrderQueue[(self.Orderbook[i][j][0])][action].put(i)
                self.OperationQueue[(self.Orderbook[i][j][0])][action].put(j)
                self.QueueCounter[(self.Orderbook[i][j][0])][action] = self.OrderQueue[(self.Orderbook[i][j][0])][action].qsize()


                observation = self.getObservation(i,j)
                reward = self.getReward(observation)


                print((self.Orderbook[i][j][0]),action,"Put in Queue: (Group,Resource),Order,Operation:",i,",",j,"Resource Queue Length:",self.QueueCounter[(self.Orderbook[i][j][0])][action])
                
                #if queue is empty start the operation
                if self.ResourcesStatus[(self.Orderbook[i][j][0])][action] == 0:
                    NextOrder = self.OrderQueue[(self.Orderbook[i][j][0])][action].get()
                    NextOperation = self.OperationQueue[(self.Orderbook[i][j][0])][action].get()
                    
                    self.yieldTimeoutEvents(env,NextOrder,NextOperation,action)

          
                yield self.env.timeout(1) 

                return observation, reward, self.done
            
                
        
    #create timeouts                        
        def yieldTimeoutEvents(self,env,i,j,action):    
            print((self.Orderbook[i][j][0]),action,"Get out of Queue: (Group,Resource),Order,Operation:",i,",",j,"CurrentTime:",env.now,"Timeoutlength:", Orderbook[i][j][1])
            self.ResourcesStatus[(self.Orderbook[i][j][0])][action] = 1

            #Set Timeout
            self.TimeoutEvents.append(simpy.events.Timeout(env,self.Orderbook[i][j][1]))
                
            #Callback for when timeout is over
            self.TimeoutEvents[len(self.TimeoutEvents) - 1].callbacks.append(lambda event: self.onTimeoutComplete(env,i,j,action))

                
            
    #when timeout complete          
        def onTimeoutComplete(self,env,i,j,action):
            
            self.Orderbook[i][0][2]+= 1 #Operationcounter +=1
            self.Orderbook[i][j][2]= 0 #Operation is beeing fullfilled
            print(self.Orderbook[i])

            #if queue not empty get next operation an yield timeout 
            if not self.OrderQueue[(self.Orderbook[i][j][0])][action].empty():
                OnTimeoutCompleteNextOrder = self.OrderQueue[(self.Orderbook[i][j][0])][action].get()
                OnTimeoutCompleteNextOperation = self.OperationQueue[(self.Orderbook[i][j][0])][action].get()
                self.yieldTimeoutEvents(env,OnTimeoutCompleteNextOrder,OnTimeoutCompleteNextOperation,action)

            #else set the status to not active
            else:   
                print((self.Orderbook[i][j][0]),action,"Finished:(Group,Resource),FinishTime: ",self.env.now) 
                self.ResourcesStatus[(self.Orderbook[i][j][0])][action] = 0  

            #choose resource for next operation in the orders operation sequence 
            if j < self.nOperationsPerVariant[(self.Orderbook[i][0][1])]+1:    
                self.env.process(self.step(env,i,j+1))


#Resets/Initializes the whole digital Twin and starts simulation     
        def reset(self):
            #Setting of Parameters for Resources
            #4x Pick & Place (nMachinesPerOperation[0])
            #6x Schrauben (nMachinesPerOperation[1])
            #2x Qualitätskontrolle + Verpackung (nMachinesPerOperation[2])
            self.nMachinesPerOperation = [4, 6, 2]


            #Buffersize shall be 5-10 to realistically portray the Workshop
            self.BufferSize = 10


            #Strictness of how tight the deadine ist(1=very strict; 1,4=not so strict)
            self.StrictnessDeadline=1.2 

            #Setting of Parameters for Orders
            self.nOrders = 20 #Count of Orders in Orderbook created at initialization/ maximum possible count
            self.TimespanCreateorders = 250 #Timespan after which to create new orders


            #Building of Variants
            #Line 0-3: possible variants
            #Row 0-6: strictly to be followed sequence of necessary operations
            #For each Operation:["Resourcegroud needed for Operation", "Required Time for Operation"]
            self.Variants = [[[0, 69], [1, 75], [0, 15], [1, 37], [2, 35], [0, 0], [0, 0]],
                            [[0, 81], [1, 37], [0, 15], [1, 75], [0, 15], [1, 37], [2, 35]],
                            [[0, 58], [1, 75], [0, 15], [1, 37], [2, 35], [0, 0], [0, 0]],
                            [[0, 70], [1, 37], [0, 15], [1, 75], [0, 15], [1, 37], [2, 35]]]


            #Numbers of Operations necessary for each variant/ length of each line 
            #(just because of implementation issues later on all lines have same dimensionality,)
            #(Operations with [0, 0] shall be ignored)
            #(if Variants.shape[1] != len(nMachinesPerOperation): FAult!)
            self.nOperationsPerVariant = [5, 7, 5, 7]   
            self.lenVariants = 7  


            #Build Orderbook
            #[[[Deadline, Variant, Counter],[Resourcegroup, Time, Status],[Resourcegroup, Time, Status],...]
            # [[Deadline, Variant, Counter],[Resourcegroup, Time, Status],[Resourcegroup, Time, Status],...
            # [[Deadline, Variant, Counter],[Resourcegroup, Time, Status],[Resourcegroup, Time, Status]]
            self.Orderbook = [[[0 for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(self.lenVariants+ 1)] for _ in range(self.nOrders)]
            for a in range(self.nOrders):
                VariantChoice = random.randint(0, len(self.Variants)-1) 
                self.Orderbook[a][0][0] = 258*self.nOrders*self.StrictnessDeadline
                self.Orderbook[a][0][1] = VariantChoice  
                #Orderbook[a][0][2] = 0 #Counter for Operations in this order
                for b in range(1, self.nOperationsPerVariant[VariantChoice]+1):
                    self.Orderbook[a][b][0] = self.Variants[VariantChoice][b-1][0]
                    self.Orderbook[a][b][1] = self.Variants[VariantChoice][b-1][1]
                    self.Orderbook[a][b][2] = 1 #Status of Operation(1 = Not Done; 0 = Done)


            #Status(0 = Idle, 1 = In Operation)
            self.ResourcesStatus = []
            for k in range(len(self.nMachinesPerOperation)):
                self.ResourcesStatus.append([0 for l in range(self.nMachinesPerOperation[k])])


            #Queues of pending Operations for each Resource
            self.OrderQueue = [[queue.Queue() for j in range(self.nMachinesPerOperation[i])] for i in range(len(self.nMachinesPerOperation))]
            self.OperationQueue = [[queue.Queue() for j in range(self.nMachinesPerOperation[i])] for i in range(len(self.nMachinesPerOperation))]
            self.QueueCounter = [[[0 for j in range(self.nMachinesPerOperation[i])] for i in range(len(self.nMachinesPerOperation))]]

            #Init of global variable for signaling line of new created order in orderbook
            self.LineOfNewOrder = 0


            #Array for Timeouts
            self.TimeoutEvents= []

            self.done = False

            #Build Environment
            #self.env = simpy.Environment()

            #Start Simulation        
            self.env.process(self.initProcesses(self.env))
            self.env.process(self.CreateOrdersInit(self.env))

            #set runtime
            self.env.run(until=7000)

            #observation starts with first operation of first order
            observation = self.getObservation(0,1)

            return observation

    
    


        


        def getObservation(self,i,j):
            
            observation = {
                

                        

                        "AuftragVariante": numpy.array([self.Orderbook[i][0][1]], dtype=int),
                        #"AuftragOperationstyp": numpy.array([self.Orderbook[i][j][0]], dtype=int),
                        #"AuftragOperationszeit": numpy.array([self.Orderbook[i][j][1]], dtype=float),
                        #"AuftragSlackzeit": numpy.array([self.Orderbook[i][0][0]- self.env.now], dtype=float),#NICHT SLACK,restliche Beabeitungszeit#-übrige Operationen dann passts
                        #"AuftragFortschritt":numpy.array([j/(self.nOperationsPerVariant[self.Orderbook[i][0][1]])], dtype=float),
                        #"AuftragErwartungVerspätung": getAuftragErwartungVerspätung,
                        #"SystemVerweildauer": 
                        #"MaschineStandardabweichungPufferauslastung":
                        #"MaschineMedianPufferauslastung": numpy.array([numpy.median(self.QueueCounter[(self.Orderbook[i][j][0])])], dtype=float),
                        #"SystemMedianPufferauslastung":numpy.array([numpy.median(self.QueueCounter)], dtype=float)
            }
        
            return observation
        
        def getReward(self,observation):
            
            reward = -2 + numpy.exp(0.69 * observation["SystemMedianPufferauslastung"])
            #print("reward:",reward)
            return reward  
        

            
#Build Environment
env = FJSP()
model = PPO('MlpPolicy',env=env)
model.learn(total_timesteps=100)
obs = env.reset()
for i in range(1000):
    action, __state = model.predict(obs, deterministic=True)
    obs, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
    if done:
      obs = env.reset()
```

I am very much looking forward to your answers